# Select Random Page Image with ProcessWire

Tags: php

I'm just starting out using the ProcessWire system and really enjoying it.

On my Home Page, I would like to display an image from a random page. The page can be ANY page as long as the it is the child of the parent page with ID '1010'.

Is it possible, and if so, how do I achieve this?

My current code for showing the home page image is this:
`if($page->image) echo "<img src='{$page->image->url}'>";` however, I'd like to select a random image from any of the children pages of the above parent ID.

I found [this](http://processwire.com/api/arrays/page/), but wasn't sure whether it would be of any use.

Many thanks for any pointers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this in your template's code (assuming that your image field is called `image`):

```
/* Find all children of page with ID 1010 that include an image */
$allChildPages = $pages->find('parent=1010,image.count>0');

/* Select a page from all children in the PageArray randomly */
$randomChildPage = $allChildPages->getRandom();

if ($randomChildPage->image) {
    echo "<img src='{$randomChildPage->image->url}'>";
}
```

Have a look at the relevant code:

- [`$pages`](http://processwire.com/api/variables/pages/)`->`[`find()`](https://github.com/ryancramerdesign/ProcessWire/blob/2.4.0/wire/core/Pages.php#L94) returns a collection of [Pages](http://processwire.com/api/variables/page/) (matching the [Selector](http://processwire.com/api/selectors/)) as a [`PageArray`](http://processwire.com/api/arrays/page/) (that extends the [`WireArray`](http://processwire.com/api/arrays/) class).
- [`$anyWireArray`](http://processwire.com/api/arrays/)`->`[`getRandom()`](https://github.com/ryancramerdesign/ProcessWire/blob/2.4.0/wire/core/WireArray.php#L523) returns a random element of itself.

Also have a look at [this forum thread](http://processwire.com/talk/topic/328-grabbing-a-random-image/) where several strategies to randomize images from different pages are discussed.